# Angular Firebase background message

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire

I have a project with firebase push notifications. I use @angular/fire module. I'm receiving messages when the page is opened, but in the background, I get only push notification, but angularfire doesn't give me the message. And also I couldn't change the notification icon and title. I do it in firebase-messaging-sw.js

```
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
   console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
   var notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
   var notificationOptions = {
       body: 'My message',
       icon: '/mylogo.png'
   };
   return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
   notificationOptions);
});
```

Comment: Hello. I'm in the same situation. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Yes, you can't get push notifications with this way. Push is only for receiving notification. If you want to get history you need to make it with backend.

Comment: I am also in same situation, would you please explain your solution a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this work by adding this code to my firebase-messaging-sw.js file

> messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function (payload) {
> return payload; });

```
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.3/firebase-app-compat.js");
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.3/firebase-messaging-compat.js");

firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "xxx",
    authDomain: "xxx",
    projectId: "xxx",
    storageBucket: "xxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxx",
    appId: "xxx",
});
const messaging = firebase.messaging();


messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function (payload) {
    return payload;
});
```

but had some difficulties making this work with google Chrome .. It worked with Firefox